# Function to GetMaxValueOffset?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a one line column calculation that can find out the index OFFSET from the current row backwards, using a window size.

For example, given this dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a reproducible, static dataframe.
# 1 minute SPY data. Skip to the bottom...
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:30",
        "open": "457.2",
        "high": "457.29",
        "low": "456.78",
        "close": "456.9383",
        "volume": "594142"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:31",
        "open": "456.94",
        "high": "457.07",
        "low": "456.8",
        "close": "456.995",
        "volume": "194061"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:32",
        "open": "456.99",
        "high": "457.22",
        "low": "456.84",
        "close": "457.21",
        "volume": "186114"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:33",
        "open": "457.22",
        "high": "457.45",
        "low": "457.2011",
        "close": "457.308",
        "volume": "294158"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:34",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.4",
        "low": "457.25",
        "close": "457.32",
        "volume": "172574"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:35",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "396668"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:36",
        "open": "457.48",
        "high": "457.6511",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "186777"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:37",
        "open": "457.5699",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.5699",
        "close": "457.69",
        "volume": "187596"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:38",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.73",
        "low": "457.54",
        "close": "457.63",
        "volume": "185570"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:39",
        "open": "457.63",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.59",
        "volume": "164707"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:40",
        "open": "457.59",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.7199",
        "volume": "167438"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:41",
        "open": "457.72",
        "high": "457.8",
        "low": "457.68",
        "close": "457.72",
        "volume": "199951"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:42",
        "open": "457.73",
        "high": "457.74",
        "low": "457.6",
        "close": "457.62",
        "volume": "152134"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:43",
        "open": "457.6",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.5077",
        "volume": "142530"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:44",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.4001",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "122575"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:45",
        "open": "457.61",
        "high": "457.76",
        "low": "457.58",
        "close": "457.75",
        "volume": "119886"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:46",
        "open": "457.74",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "183157"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:47",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.37",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "128542"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:48",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.49",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "154181"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:49",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.5898",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "163063"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:50",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.59",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.555",
        "volume": "96229"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:51",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.61",
        "low": "457.31",
        "close": "457.4217",
        "volume": "110380"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:52",
        "open": "457.42",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.47",
        "volume": "107518"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:53",
        "open": "457.475",
        "high": "457.51",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.48",
        "volume": "78062"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:54",
        "open": "457.49",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.42",
        "close": "457.46",
        "volume": "133883"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:55",
        "open": "457.47",
        "high": "457.56",
        "low": "457.45",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "98998"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:56",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.43",
        "close": "457.43",
        "volume": "110237"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:57",
        "open": "457.43",
        "high": "457.65",
        "low": "457.375",
        "close": "457.65",
        "volume": "98794"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:58",
        "open": "457.66",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.35",
        "close": "457.45",
        "volume": "262154"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:59",
        "open": "457.45",
        "high": "457.47",
        "low": "457.33",
        "close": "457.4",
        "volume": "74685"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:00",
        "open": "457.41",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.38",
        "volume": "166617"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:01",
        "open": "457.39",
        "high": "457.7",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.5",
        "volume": "265649"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:02",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.57",
        "low": "457.39",
        "close": "457.53",
        "volume": "131947"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:03",
        "open": "457.53",
        "high": "457.54",
        "low": "457.4",
        "close": "457.51",
        "volume": "80111"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:04",
        "open": "457.51",
        "high": "457.62",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.6101",
        "volume": "117174"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:05",
        "open": "457.621",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.51",
        "close": "457.58",
        "volume": "168758"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:06",
        "open": "457.58",
        "high": "457.64",
        "low": "457.46",
        "close": "457.61",
        "volume": "84076"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:07",
        "open": "457.62",
        "high": "457.7401",
        "low": "457.62",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "125156"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:08",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.69",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.67",
        "volume": "116919"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:09",
        "open": "457.69",
        "high": "457.72",
        "low": "457.5",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "102551"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:10",
        "open": "457.56",
        "high": "457.75",
        "low": "457.56",
        "close": "457.7",
        "volume": "109165"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:11",
        "open": "457.7",
        "high": "457.725",
        "low": "457.63",
        "close": "457.66",
        "volume": "146209"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:12",
        "open": "457.665",
        "high": "457.88",
        "low": "457.64",
        "close": "457.86",
        "volume": "210620"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:13",
        "open": "457.855",
        "high": "457.96",
        "low": "457.83",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "159975"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:14",
        "open": "457.95",
        "high": "458.02",
        "low": "457.93",
        "close": "457.95",
        "volume": "152042"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:15",
        "open": "457.96",
        "high": "458.15",
        "low": "457.96",
        "close": "458.08",
        "volume": "146047"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:16",
        "open": "458.085",
        "high": "458.17",
        "low": "457.99",
        "close": "458.15",
        "volume": "100732"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:17",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.33",
        "low": "458.155",
        "close": "458.245",
        "volume": "235072"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:18",
        "open": "458.25",
        "high": "458.29",
        "low": "458.14",
        "close": "458.16",
        "volume": "422002"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:19",
        "open": "458.17",
        "high": "458.2801",
        "low": "458.1699",
        "close": "458.28",
        "volume": "114611"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:20",
        "open": "458.29",
        "high": "458.39",
        "low": "458.24",
        "close": "458.37",
        "volume": "241797"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:21",
        "open": "458.37",
        "high": "458.42",
        "low": "458.31",
        "close": "458.345",
        "volume": "124824"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 10:22",
        "open": "458.33",
        "high": "458.49",
        "low": "458.33",
        "close": "458.47",
        "volume": "132125"
    }
])
```

... and using the below code...

```
# Convert close to numeric re: the .csv to .json
# converter tool I used online...
df['close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['close'])

# Define the lookback length
lookback_window = 20

# Define a blank target column
df['MaxIndexOffset'] = None

# WORKING EXAMPLE
# Iterate through the df
for i in range(lookback_window, len(df)):

    # Convert the current chunk of rows to a list and reverse it
    curr_range = df['close'].iloc[i-lookback_window:i].to_list()
    curr_range.reverse()
    # Then find the max between 0 and the first instance of the max
    # value. The first instance (because we reversed the order) will
    # be the number I need. If the current row IS the max value, then
    # the offset will be 0. If the max value is 2 bars ago, it'll be 2, etc.
    x1 = max(0, curr_range.index(max(curr_range)))
    df['MaxIndexOffset'].iloc[i] = x1

# Export the correct answer dataset to compare the next function
# to below
df.to_csv("correct_answers.csv", index=False)

# NON-WORKING EXAMPLE
# What I'd like to do is NOT use a for loop to do the above. I envision
# we can use np.where() here? But I don't know how yet. Psuedo might look
# something like:
df['MaxIndexOffset2'] = i - (df['close'].rolling(window=lookback_window).tolist().reverse().index(max(df['close'].rolling(window=lookback_window))))
# ... but obviously doesn't work. "AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'to_list'"

# Check for matches
df.to_csv("correct_answers2.csv", index=False)
```

...is there a way to do this without the `for` loop? I'm looking to get the offset (i.e. number of rows back from the current row, up to the `lookback_window`) of the max value in that window. If there are multiples of the same max value, it should just return the closest one from the current row. Any ideas??? Thanks!

Comment: The calculations seems bit off to me. Why is the last row assigned the `MaxIndexOffset` value of `1`? It should be `0` to be exact.

Comment: I think you need to modify your existing for-loop logic to get the correct calculations: Replace `range(lookback_window, len(df))` with `range(lookback_window, len(df) + 1)` and `df['MaxIndexOffset'].iloc[i] = x1` with `df['MaxIndexOffset'].iloc[i - 1] = x1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the `close` column, then apply **[`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)** on a `rolling` `window` of size equal to `lookback_window` then **[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)** the result upwards and assign it to the column `MaxIndexOffset`

```
df['MaxIndexOffset'] = df['close'][::-1].rolling(lookback_window)\
                         .apply(np.argmax, raw=True).shift(-lookback_window + 1)
```

---

```
                time      open      high       low     close  volume  MaxIndexOffset
0    2021-10-26 9:30     457.2    457.29    456.78  456.9383  594142             NaN
1    2021-10-26 9:31    456.94    457.07     456.8  456.9950  194061             NaN
2    2021-10-26 9:32    456.99    457.22    456.84  457.2100  186114             NaN
3    2021-10-26 9:33    457.22    457.45  457.2011  457.3080  294158             NaN
4    2021-10-26 9:34    457.31     457.4    457.25  457.3200  172574             NaN
5    2021-10-26 9:35    457.31    457.48    457.18  457.4400  396668             NaN
6    2021-10-26 9:36    457.48  457.6511    457.44  457.5700  186777             NaN
7    2021-10-26 9:37  457.5699    457.73  457.5699  457.6900  187596             NaN
8    2021-10-26 9:38     457.7    457.73    457.54  457.6300  185570             NaN
9    2021-10-26 9:39    457.63    457.64    457.31  457.5900  164707             NaN
10   2021-10-26 9:40    457.59    457.72    457.46  457.7199  167438             NaN
11   2021-10-26 9:41    457.72     457.8    457.68  457.7200  199951             NaN
12   2021-10-26 9:42    457.73    457.74     457.6  457.6200  152134             NaN
13   2021-10-26 9:43     457.6    457.65    457.45  457.5077  142530             NaN
14   2021-10-26 9:44    457.51    457.64  457.4001  457.6100  122575             NaN
15   2021-10-26 9:45    457.61    457.76    457.58  457.7500  119886             NaN
16   2021-10-26 9:46    457.74    457.75    457.37  457.3800  183157             NaN
17   2021-10-26 9:47    457.42    457.49    457.37  457.4400  128542             NaN
18   2021-10-26 9:48    457.43    457.49    457.33  457.4400  154181             NaN
19   2021-10-26 9:49    457.43  457.5898    457.42  457.4700  163063             4.0
20   2021-10-26 9:50    457.45    457.59    457.44  457.5550   96229             5.0
21   2021-10-26 9:51    457.56    457.61    457.31  457.4217  110380             6.0
22   2021-10-26 9:52    457.42    457.56    457.42  457.4700  107518             7.0
23   2021-10-26 9:53   457.475    457.51     457.4  457.4800   78062             8.0
24   2021-10-26 9:54    457.49    457.57    457.42  457.4600  133883             9.0
25   2021-10-26 9:55    457.47    457.56    457.45  457.5100   98998            10.0
26   2021-10-26 9:56    457.51    457.54    457.43  457.4300  110237            11.0
27   2021-10-26 9:57    457.43    457.65   457.375  457.6500   98794            12.0
28   2021-10-26 9:58    457.66    457.69    457.35  457.4500  262154            13.0
29   2021-10-26 9:59    457.45    457.47    457.33  457.4000   74685            14.0
30  2021-10-26 10:00    457.41    457.48    457.18  457.3800  166617            15.0
31  2021-10-26 10:01    457.39     457.7    457.39  457.5000  265649            16.0
32  2021-10-26 10:02    457.51    457.57    457.39  457.5300  131947            17.0
33  2021-10-26 10:03    457.53    457.54     457.4  457.5100   80111            18.0
34  2021-10-26 10:04    457.51    457.62     457.5  457.6101  117174            19.0
35  2021-10-26 10:05   457.621    457.64    457.51  457.5800  168758             8.0
36  2021-10-26 10:06    457.58    457.64    457.46  457.6100   84076             9.0
37  2021-10-26 10:07    457.62  457.7401    457.62  457.6600  125156             0.0
38  2021-10-26 10:08   457.665    457.69     457.5  457.6700  116919             0.0
39  2021-10-26 10:09    457.69    457.72     457.5  457.5700  102551             1.0
40  2021-10-26 10:10    457.56    457.75    457.56  457.7000  109165             0.0
41  2021-10-26 10:11     457.7   457.725    457.63  457.6600  146209             1.0
42  2021-10-26 10:12   457.665    457.88    457.64  457.8600  210620             0.0
43  2021-10-26 10:13   457.855    457.96    457.83  457.9500  159975             0.0
44  2021-10-26 10:14    457.95    458.02    457.93  457.9500  152042             0.0
45  2021-10-26 10:15    457.96    458.15    457.96  458.0800  146047             0.0
46  2021-10-26 10:16   458.085    458.17    457.99  458.1500  100732             0.0
47  2021-10-26 10:17    458.17    458.33   458.155  458.2450  235072             0.0
48  2021-10-26 10:18    458.25    458.29    458.14  458.1600  422002             1.0
49  2021-10-26 10:19    458.17  458.2801  458.1699  458.2800  114611             0.0
50  2021-10-26 10:20    458.29    458.39    458.24  458.3700  241797             0.0
51  2021-10-26 10:21    458.37    458.42    458.31  458.3450  124824             1.0
52  2021-10-26 10:22    458.33    458.49    458.33  458.4700  132125             0.0
```